# pytest -- version Errors

Tags: python, pip, pytest

I am trying to install the Pytest package via pip. When I go to check the version of pytest that I installed, it throws the following instead of printing the version of pytest that has been installed. Did anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Thanks for your help!

```
python --version
```

[image: python version]

```
3.4.0
```

```
pip --version
```

[image: pip version]

```
pip 1.5.4
```

```
pytest --version
```

[image: pytest version error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 3.4 is very old, as is pip 1.5.4

I'd suggest upgrading both

in the latest version of pytest, we've dropped support for python<3.5 -- usually if you have a sufficiently new version of `pip` it will avoid downloading the incorrect version of pytest (in the case of python3.4, the latest supported version of pytest is 4.6.x) -- however you need at least pip 9 for that

if you are unable to upgrade, you should pin to an old-enough version of pytest, in this case `pip install "pytest<5"`

disclaimer: I'm a core dev for pytest

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, some code involved in the test depends on the `typing` module that was introduced in Python 3.5.  So, switching to python version 3.5+ should fix the issue.